# I am not being able to generate the subsets of an array basing on giving Sum

Tags: c, recursion

I am using a recursive function to find the subsets from a character array basing on a given sum:

```
str="1234567890"
```

`n=2` (size of subset), `m=9` (the given sum).
Solution: `{9,0},{0,9},{8,1},{1,8},{7,2},{2,7},,,,,{5,4},{4,5}`.
My code is following.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void genrate(char*,int,int,int);
int main(){
    char str[20]="1234567890";
    genrate(str,2,9,10);
}
void genrate(char *str,int n,int m,int k){
    int i,j,sum;
    sum=0;
    if(sum==m){
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            printf("%c ",str[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    sum+=(int)str[k]-48;
    genrate(str,n,m,k);
    genrate(str,n,m,k-1);
}
```

Comment: `sum=0; if (sum==m)`. That's only true when `m==0`, and since `m` is 9, it's never true. Perhaps you meant to pass `sum` as one of the function parameters.

Comment: A simple solution would be to iterate over all permutations, and then prune that set.

Comment: Variables n. m, k, i, j. Some local, some parameters. That's not confusing at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is not giving a solution but I just want to point some errors regarding recursion.

First of all local variables is not a good idea, for example the variable `sum` will be redefined in the next recursive call as this new call will execute `int i,j,sum;` initialisaion, I printed address of sum and check :

```
Address of SUM : 5f7ac8
Address of SUM : 5f7a98
Address of SUM : 5f7a68
Address of SUM : 5f7a38
Address of SUM : 5f7a08
```

It changes at each call ...

and the second call to `genrate(str, n, m, k - 1)` will never be called ... As it will always stuck in an endless call-loop {generate() -> generate() -> generate() ->).

In recursive functions you need to define a condition in which the recursivity ends, in your case there is no ending condition ...

For example factoriel :

```
long int fact(int n) {
    if (n>=1)
        return n*fact(n-1);
    else
        return 1; // Here the end of the recursivity !
}
```

Regards.

Comment: It means i need to make another function like a wrapper which could return the subsets ?